# Laplace transform without step function

Tags: laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

Find the Laplace transform

$$Y(s) = \mathcal{L(y)}$$

$$y'' + 4y = \begin{cases}
1, & 0\le t < \pi\\
0, & \pi\le t< \infty
\end{cases} $$
$$y(0) = 1$$
$$y'(0) = 0$$

I start by working with the left part of the equation: $$y'' + 4y = \mathcal{L}(y)(s^2+1)+sy(0)+y'(0)=\mathcal{L}(y)(s^2+1)+s$$
$$\mathcal{L}(y)(s^2+1)+s = \mathcal{L}(\begin{cases}
1, & 0\le t < \pi\\
0, & \pi\le t< \infty
\end{cases}) $$

But I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: In that case, follow this example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250599/how-can-the-laplace-transform-be-used-to-solve-piecewise-functions

Comment: Thank you so much! What I did was, I followed your example for the right part of the equation, and put it equal to the left part I had calculated in my post. And this solved it for me, thank you (again)!